# qrtz schedulers running in all the clones of application server

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, timertask

Do we have any support from quartz_scheduler or spring framework for running a scheduled job in all the clones (instances) of the application server?

In my Project, we are having 2 instances of Application server for load balancing. During server start up using singleton bean creation, we are storing some important details in cache memory of JVM and we need to refresh the cache memory when some data changes without restarting the server.

If the quartz - scheduler runs in server1 , the cache memory won't get refreshed in server2 and vice versa. So i need a permanent solution for this problem and i should be able to control the job by update queries. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Quartz in a cluster configuration, scheduled job will run only on exactly one, random instance. Currently you cannot schedule a job to run on all nodes in a cluster. On the other hand if each application runs independent Quartz scheduler, they don't know nothing about each other. Thus if you schedule a job on one instance, it will run on the exact same instance.

What you really need is not a distributed job scheduling (I guess you are scheduling a job to asynchronously update the cache on both instances), but **distributed caching**. The idea is that every time you update the cache, the changes are automatically replicated to all other instances. Also Spring provides some caching abstraction via `@Cacheable` annotation.

Check out [ehcache](/questions/tagged/ehcache) with RMI replication, [terracotta](/questions/tagged/terracotta), [hazelcast](/questions/tagged/hazelcast) and many others. They do much better job wrt. caching and distributing changes.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz for your quick reply. One more concern for me is controlling cache memory through Database entries similar to quartz. So that we can control the job for refreshing the cache memory in all the nodes of a cluster